# My Google Play App was suspended - how to reactivate it?

Tags: android, google-play

I had developed and published in Google Play an app called AppCoins (http://appcoins.mobi/?setLng=en) that is a micro-jobs service mostly about incentive installs of misc apps and services, or watching video ads and other promo offers including cashback offers. So users get paid when they do some offers using my app. 
My app does not offer any payouts based on the excitement (gambling), but provides service such as well known apps Tapporo (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tapporo) and Whaff (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whaff.whaff) and some others do.

On 14th of nov 2013 I launched the app (mobi.appcoins) in Google Play and on 18 march I got email from Google Play Team stating that my app is suspended. REASON FOR REMOVAL: Violation of the gambling provision of the Content Policy. I carefully read the policy to check what this can mean, but did`nt understand what particular I`m violating. I have NO relationship to gambling and believe that this block is a mistake.

### I wrote an appeal but got a bot-style answer:

Thank you for your note. 
We have reviewed your appeal and will not be reinstating your app. This decision is final and we will not be responding to any additional emails regarding this removal.

If your account is still in good standing and the nature of your app allows for republishing you may consider releasing a new, policy compliant version of your app to Google Play under a new package name. We are unable to comment further on the specific policy basis for this removal or provide guidance on bringing future versions of your app into policy compliance. Instead, please reference theREASON FOR REMOVAL in the initial notification email from Google Play.

### Please note that additional violations may result in a suspension of your Google Play Developer account.

So after getting a response to my appeal I launched an app for second time (mobi.appcoins.appcoins) but on 11 of apr 2014 it was suspended again with the same reason for removal!

How can I get the explaination of the reason of blocking if it is not an error? because I really don't understand what is the problem with my app. This happens for the second time, but I don`t understand what is the problem and how I can fix it. Reading the rules and policies does`nt help because my app is not about gambling. 
How I can fix it if I don't know what the problem?!

Comment: google wants to blackmail you :)

Comment: I have no idea how to solve your issue and I feel for you, but stack overflow is not an appropriate place to post this; your problem has nothing to do with programming it has to do with some third party's policies. Perhaps another site on the stack exchange network supports this issue as an acceptable topic, I don't know.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terms of service for a distribution channel and reported violations of those terms, not programming. This is the sort of thing you need to be discussing with qualified legal counsel.

Comment: StackOverflow is the very 1st page where I search for help in any phase of the application lifecycle. Publishing an app is also a part of the cycle. I find it ON-topic.

Comment: I agree with @zatziky, mods and users complain of off-topic (and close questions) but most times don't offer any other channels for a user to get help.  It's really frustrating the amount of closed questions because of off-topic in here when they have to deal with many aspects of development life-cycle.

I have recently been emailed by Google Play and am looking for ways to help me out and am coming up empty handed.

Comment: @Dmitry i have seen that your app is live with "mobi.appcoins". Can you please tell me what is the issue with your application. I am facing the same. My developer account is suspended yesterday. Please help me.

Comment: @Dmitry Did you find any solution? i m also facing the same. did you upload new app with same package name?